# Как сделать круглые цифры при изменении размера шрифта?

Tags: html, css

При изменении размера шрифта цифра становится уже овальной, что посоветуете?

```css
.production__number {
  font-size: 14px;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 5px 10px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 border: 4px solid #000;
}
```

```html
   <p class="production__number">
    1
   </p>
```

Comment: посоветую сделать круг псевдоэлементом

Comment: и каким образом сделать с учетом изменения размера шрифта?

Answer (score 3):

Задайте размер круга в единицах размера шрифта:

```
.production__number {
  width: 1.1em;
  height: 1.1em;
}
```

```css
.production__number {
  font-size: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.1em;
  height: 1.1em;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<p class="production__number">
  1
</p>
```